# How to transform a list of enums to another type of enum in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, list-comprehension, haskell-platform

I'm trying to write a function that creates a full deck of cards (52 with no Jokers). I'm still new to this, I'm thinking that some sort of list comprehension is what I need to do, but I don't know quite how to write it (see `createHandFromList` function). I'm also guessing it needs to be recursive so that it will keep going. Anyway, here's what my code looks like so far, any help and advice is, as always, much appreciated.

```
data Card = Card Rank Suit
      deriving (Eq, Show)

data Rank = Numeric Integer | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data Hand = Empty | Add Card Hand
            deriving (Eq, Show)

fullDeck :: Hand
fullDeck = createHandFromList (suitedCardList Clubs ++
                suitedCardList Diamonds ++
                suitedCardList Hearts ++
                suitedCardList Spades)

suitedCardList :: Suit -> [Card]
suitedCardList s = [Card (Numeric 2) s, Card (Numeric 3) s,
                    Card (Numeric 4) s, Card (Numeric 5) s,
                    Card (Numeric 6) s, Card (Numeric 7) s,
                    Card (Numeric 8) s, Card (Numeric 8) s,
                    Card (Numeric 10) s, Card Jack s,
                    Card Queen s, Card King s, Card Ace s]

createHandFromList :: [Card] -> Hand -> Hand
createHandFromList [c:cs] h = [Add card h | card <- c]
```

Currently, the code returns this as an error:

```
BlackJack.hs:107:21: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Card’ with actual type ‘[[Card]]’
    • In the pattern: c : cs
      In the pattern: [c : cs]
      In an equation for ‘createHandFromList’:
          createHandFromList [c : cs] h = [Add card h | card <- c]
    |
107 | createHandFromList [c:cs] h = [Add card h | card <- c]     |                     ^^^^

BlackJack.hs:107:31: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Hand’ with actual type ‘[Hand]’
    • In the expression: [Add card h | card <- c]
      In an equation for ‘createHandFromList’:
          createHandFromList [c : cs] h = [Add card h | card <- c]
    |
107 | createHandFromList [c:cs] h = [Add card h | card <- c]     |
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here? It will be much easier to help you with this problem if you have a specific question we can answer. **EDIT:** Actually, never mind. I somehow managed to miss the part where you said that you’re trying to make a full deck of cards.

Comment: Hint: take a look at `foldr`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr

Comment: Also, by the way, your `suitedCardList` function can be more easily written as `[Card v s | v <- [Numeric 1, Numeric 2, Numeric 3, Numeric 4, Numeric 5, Numeric 6, Numeric 7, Numeric 8, Numeric 9, Numeric 10, Jack, Queen King, Ace]]`. It also seems a bit odd to me that you list both `Numeric 1` and `Ace` as ranks.

Comment: @Alex After looking at your code I do actually see a small problem with your `fullDeck` function: `createHandFromList` requires two parameters, but you’ve only supplied one parameter to it. Could this be the cause of your problem?

Comment: @bradrn I don't think it is, although it is needed to be changed (which I have done on my actual code file now), it still errors on the `createHandFromList` function.

Comment: @Alex Can you tell us what the error is then? That will make the problem a lot easier to solve.

Comment: Thanks @Alex! That tells me exactly what the error is: in `createHandFromList`, your `[c:cs]` should actually be `(c:cs)`.

Comment: @bradrn unfortunately, this solution still causes errors, just of a different kind, I'll update the question, so everyone sees the result, but still thanks, it's a step forward!

Comment: @Alex I think the problem now is that `createHandFromList` is returning a list of `Hand`s, but its type signature states that it returns a single `Hand` value. I suggest that you implement this function with recursion rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: to answer your Q's title, not body, you do it with `deriving Enum` and then use `fromEnum` and `toEnum`.

Comment: @bradrn how would I do that, I was thinking something like `createHandFromList (c:cs) h = Add c h + createHandFromList (cs) h` but I have no idea how to get haskell to do something after the other thing, I know it's not add, but for sake of understanding my logic, I left it in.

Comment: @Alex That’s almost correct. I believe the correct implementation is `createHandFromList (c:cs) h = Add c (createHandFromList cs h)`; that is, add card `c` to the `Hand` created from adding `cs` to `h`. But you’ll also need a base case for `createHandFromList [] h`.

Comment: @bradrn perfect! thank you very much, if you wanted to post that as the answer I'd be more than happy to upvote it again and mark as right.

Comment: @WillNess I don't think he can auto derive `Enum` instances by `deriving` for the `Card` and `Hand` types.. also possibly `Rank` since they have one or more non-nullary data constructors. (constructors with fields). Can this be done..?

Comment: FWIW, here's one way to create a full deck of cards: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/10/08/full-deck

Comment: Rolled back edit because it eliminated the problem with `[c:cs]` without updating the error. There are multiple problems with the code; don't edit the question as they are pointed out in the comments. Close the question, or (since no answer has yet been posted), simplify it to focus on a problem that *still exists*.

Comment: @Redu in the *title* it says "a list of *enums*"...

Comment: This problem could be simplified away. Look at the declaration of lists: `data [] a = [] | a : [a]`. Get a concrete type out of this: `[Card] = [] | Card : [Card]`. Look familiar? Your `Hand` type is nothing more than a list of `Card`s.

Comment: @Alex I’d be happy to post that as an answer! (But you don’t need to upvote it: acceptance gives me reputation anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this code. Firstly, you have used `[c:cs]` as a pattern in the definition of `createHandFromList`. However, this is a syntax error: in pattern matching, the syntax is `(c:cs)`. This gives the following code:

```hs
createHandFromList :: [Card] -> Hand -> Hand
createHandFromList (c:cs) h = [Add card h | card <- c]
```

But there is still another problem with this code. You return a list of `Hand`s, but the type signature says that you must return a single `Hand`! Clearly this is wrong. To figure out what to do instead, let’s take a step back and work through exactly what `createHandFromList` should do:

- Starting with the hand it is given, add one card to that hand
- Add another card to the hand just created
- Add another card to the hand just created
- …
- Repeat until no cards are left.

This can be done most easily with recursion:

```hs
createHandFromList :: [Card] -> Hand -> Hand
-- Add card ‘c’ to the result of (createHandFromList cs h)
createHandFromList (c:cs) h = Add c (createHandFromList cs h)
-- Return hand ‘h’ if there are no more cards left to add
createHandFromList [] h = h
```

---

There is a small simplification I want to address as well. (Credit goes to @Khuldraeseth na'Barya, who wrote this in the comments.) Let’s look at the possible values of `Hand`:

- `Empty`
- `Add card1 Empty`
- `Add card2 (Add card1 Empty)`
- `Add card3 (Add card2 (Add card1 Empty))`
- etc.

This looks exactly like a list of `Card`s! And it turns out that the types `Hand` and `[Card]` are isomorphic. In pseudo-Haskell:

```hs
data Hand   = Empty | Add Card Hand
data [Card] = []    | :   Card [Card]
```

So, if you represent `Hand` as something like `newtype Hand = Hand { getCards :: [Card] }`, then you should be able to replace the recursion by a list comprehension. This is left as an exercise for the reader.